# Rails Masonry GEM issues with Bootstrap Tab-pane

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, masonry

I'm using the bootstrap tab-pane inside of my rails application. Inside of each tab I want to use the Masonry GEM. However, all the items are stacking on top of eachother.

```
.container
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs
    - if @project.user == current_user
      %li
        %a{href: new_project_room_path(@project)} <i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i> Add Room
    - @rooms.each do |room|
      %li
        %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "##{dom_id(room)}"}= room.title


  .tab-content

    - @rooms.each do |room|
      .tab-pane{id: dom_id(room)}
        .container-fluid.page.page-block
          .masonry-container.centered.transitions-enabled.infinite-scroll.clearfix
            - room.products.each do |product|
              .box.col3
                = product.title
```

If I resize the page, they display side by side, the way I want them to. How can I get it to display like this all the time?

Also as an FYI, when I use similar code not inside of a tab-pane, everything works fine.

```
.container-fluid.page.page-block
  .masonry-container.centered.transitions-enabled.infinite-scroll.clearfix
    - if current_user.is_designer?
      = link_to new_project_path do
        .box.col3.create_projects_well#add_project
          %span.text-center#create_project
            %i.fa.fa-plus-circle.fa-3x
            %br
            Add a project

    - @projects.each do |project|
      .box.col3
        - if project.image_url != nil
          = link_to(image_tag(project.image_url, class: "img-responsive opaq"), user_project_path(project.user, project))
        - else
          = link_to(image_tag("150.png", class: "img-responsive opaq"), user_project_path(project.user, project))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing fluid.

```
.container.page.page-block
  .masonry-container.centered.transitions-enabled.infinite-scroll.clearfix
    - if current_user.is_designer?
      = link_to new_project_path do
        .box.col3.create_projects_well#add_project
          %span.text-center#create_project
            %i.fa.fa-plus-circle.fa-3x
            %br
            Add a project
```

According to the [bootstrap fluid grid documentation](http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem), "*Nesting with fluid grids is a bit different: the number of nested columns doesn't need to match the parent. Instead, your columns are reset at each level because each row takes up 100% of the parent column.*"

Comment: Drew, you are right, removing the -fluid and just using .container fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly. But if you want to have the masonry to always be the same width you may want to checkout the isFitWidth Property

**link to masonry doc**
http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isfitwidth

```
"isFitWidth": true

/* center container with CSS */
#fit-width .masonry {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**codepen demo**
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nGLvx